# RISC-V Looping Through Array of Words

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, riscv

In my assignment for class the professor asked us to loop through an given array of 10 numbers and print them, and the following was provided as skeleton code:

```
.data
arrayOfNums:
.word 0
.word 1
.word 255
.word 65536
.word 4294967295
.word 22
.word 314159
.word 161803
.word 42
.word 131929

K: .word 1337

.text
.globl main

main:
*Code goes here*
```

I don't understand how to go down the list of words from arrayOfNums. This is my first time coming into contact with any sort of assembly language so a detailed explanation would be extremely helpful, thanks guys

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at the `la` pseudoinstruction for loading into a register the address represented by the label `arrayOfNums`. This address corresponds to the first element of the array (value `0`). Then, with this address in a register, you can dereference it to access the pointed element via the `lw` instruction. You can do this last step over and over until you have iterated through all the elements, just have to increase the register where you loaded `arrayOfNums` by four on each iteration to have the register content pointing at the next element.

Comment: Also, you don't need to write a dedicated `.word` directive for every value if they are contiguous. You can just write a single one by separating the values by commas: `.word 0, 1, 255, ...`

Comment: Pretty [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60087133/427158) with almost the same skeleton code, but including an erroneous solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have to solve the following tasks:

- load the start address of your array into a register
- loop over the array, i.e.load each element from the current address,
- print the loaded value with the right `ecall`
- increment the address of the current element by as many bytes as a word occupies,
- conditionally branch to the start of the loop if the address is still part of the array - hint: `K` symbolizes the address that immediately follows your last array element
- call an exit `ecall` to terminate your program