# Venus RISC-V how to loop, compare, and print?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am trying to loop through an array and if the number is larger than X then print.

I've tried to find tutorials online but I'm just stuck on why it is not working/outputting anything. My comments kind of explain what i tried to do.

```
.data
arrayOfNums:
.word 0
.word 1
.word 122
.word 1112
.word 4294967295
.word 22
.word 234234
.word 23332
.word 42
.word 23423

K: .word 2237

.text
.globl main

main:
####   *** vv My problem starts here vv ***   ####
la t0 K             #set t0 to K
la t1 arrayOfNums   #set t1 pointer to array
addi a1 t0 0        #add t0 deallocated to a1
addi a2 t1 0        #add t1 deallocated to a2

loop: 
    addi a0 x0 1        # print_int ecall
    addi a1 t1 0        # add t1 value to print
    ecall
    addi t1, t1, 4      # Increments t1 to move to the next element
    jal x0, loop

exit:
####Exit using environmental calls####
addi a1 x0 0         # random exit 0 
addi a0 x0 17        # print_int ecall
ecall
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is worth to mention that `Venus` is a RISC-V simulator that provides some custom syscalls: https://github.com/kvakil/venus/wiki/Environmental-Calls

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the code you have posted.

> I am trying to loop through an array and if the number is larger than X then print.

I can't find any X symbol in your code. Do you mean `K`?

> ```
> la t0 K             #set t0 to K
> ```

The comment is wrong. You load *the address* of K into `t0`. If you want to get the value that is stored at that address into `t0` you have to load the address into another register and dereference that address into `t0`, i.e. load it with the `lw` or `lwu` instruction.

> ```
> addi a1 t0 0        #add t0 deallocated to a1
> addi a2 t1 0        #add t1 deallocated to a2
> ```

What do you mean with 'deallocated to'? You copy `t0` to `a1` and `t1` to `a2`. The same could be archieved with the `mv` pseudo instruction. However, those 2 lines are superfluous as you immediately overwrite the `a1` and `a2` registers in the following lines.

> ```
>     addi a0 x0 1        # print_int ecall
>     addi a1 t1 0        # add t1 value to print
>     ecall
> ```

You could use the `li`/`mv` pseudo instructions here. This unconditionally prints the value of `t1` - which is an address. If you want to print an actual array element you would have to load it using the address stored in `t1` - cf. the `lw`/`lwu` instructions.

> ```
> addi t1, t1, 4      # Increments t1 to move to the next element
> jal x0, loop
> ```

With that you unconditionally jump to the head of the loop (with pseudo instruction: `j loop`), i.e. that means that you read over the end of your array and never quit the loop. To fix this you have to use a conditional branch instruction such as `bnez`. Meaning that you e.g. set a register (as counter) to the array size and decrement it until zero. Or set a register to the address after the last array element and branch until `t1` is equal to it.

> ```
> addi a1 x0 0         # random exit 0 
> addi a0 x0 17        # print_int ecall
> ecall
> ```

It's anything but random. The comment is incorrect, you are calling the Venus exit2 syscall, not print_int. Besides, Venus also provides an exit syscall (`10`) that doesn't require an argument.

What is completely missing from your code is a location where you are actually trying to compare numbers and then print them based on that comparison.